# JavaScript: Any chance or alternative to change the CSS Pseudo :before and :after?

Tags: javascript, css, pseudo-element

For now it feels that I've read nearly the whole stackoverflow forum to find any solution to change the pseudo elements :after and :before.

For my understanding: It can't be changed because when the browser displays it, it isn't in the DOM. But where is it then? In the browser memory???

Nevermind, it seems that it isn't possible to grab pseudo elements with :after/:before.

So I've tried another way:

```
// read CSS value      
var color = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.myCssClass'), ':before').getPropertyValue('background-color');
// write CSS value
window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.myCssClass'), ':before').setProperty('background-color', "#FF0000");
```

But ... instead of being happy, the browser returns:

```
NoModificationAllowedError: Modifications are not allowed for this document
```

OMG!!!
So there it seems that there is no workaround to change these things.

**So now my BIG question:**
Is there any other way with CSS to e.g. create an extra class that behave like the :after/:before?
I've tried it but I got totally different results.

Comment: You could always create a whole new `<style>` element with whatever new CSS you need.

Comment: The pseudo elements aren't part of the DOM, they are created by the stylesheet, and as such can't be accessed with javascript. Regular classes does not really do the same thing, so the only way to really change pseudo elements with JS is by inserting a new style tag into the head section.

Answer (score 3):

You can define classes with the `:before` or `:after` on them (example below). Browsers also make the stylesheets available via `document.styleSheets`, which is array-like. Each sheet consists of rules (which are either on the property `rules` or `cssRules` depending on the browser). The rules can be modified.

But that's messier than just defining it in your stylesheet and then using classes to manipulate it:

```
.foo:before {
    content: "before foo ";
}
.bar:before {
    content: "before bar ";
}
```

Then for instance, this HTML:

```
<div class="foo">there is stuff</div>
```

Looks like this:

```
before foo there is stuff
```

And then you can change it:

```
document.querySelector(".foo").className = "bar";
```

and it becomes:

```
before bar there is stuff
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/uXoqumu/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/uXoqumu/1/edit)